# How to remove url alias when node is deleted

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am using Pathauto. When I deleted a piece of content, I was surprised to find that its url alias was still mapped to the now-nonexistent content (node/xxx).

*How can I have this alias and System name mapping removed **automatically** when the node is deleted?*

Edit:
I want to keep the Update action set to "Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.", because I don't want paths to change when nodes are *adjusted*. However, it doesn't make sense to keep a path around if the node was deleted completely. Can I have both options somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use hook_node_delete:

```
function hook_node_delete($node){
    // Delete alias.
    $path = path_load(
      array('source' => 'node/'.$node->nid)
    );

    path_delete($path['pid']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update aliases here, or on the node

/admin/config/search/path

or bulk update a whole bunch here

/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

based on an alias pattern change set here

/admin/config/search/path/patterns

I imagine the reason it "Seems" like an alias didn't delete is because it have forwarding to another alias in a sort of chain. Drupal does clean up alaises on content delete, ou can do a simple test and see it happen. But if you have alaises chained it only seems to delete the final alais and leave the others. I think if you update you "update actions" you can minimize the number of extra alaises created.

Go here and find the section called "Update action"
/admin/config/search/path/settings

You have three choices of what to do when an alais changes

- Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.
- Create a new alias. Leave the existing alias functioning.
- Create a new alias. Delete the old alias.

Also based on there advice
"Considering installing the Redirect module to get redirects when your aliases change."

I hope this helps ans isn't off base but I faced  similar issue on a site with 500k items and the clean up was a serious issue. Best of luck!

Comment: Lots of info in this answer, but I've looked through all those options. Still don't see anything that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the path aliases here in the Admin > Config menu: admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

Comment: This neither removes the mapping nor is automatic...